# Why is this singular event spoken/written as if it were plural in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

Why is this singular event spoken/written as if it were plural in Spanish?

The statement "*I think I am going to take a vacation this week*" is translated as "*Creo que me voy a tomar unas vacaciones esta semana.*"

I would think it would be "*Creo que me voy a tomar una vacacione esta semana.*" as we're talking about *a* vacation (singular) here, not vacations (plural). What up?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The singular in Spanish would be **vacación**, but it doesn't exist. It's one of those words that only exist in plural form, like **gafas** (glasses) or **tijeras** (scissors).

And scissors doesn't have a singular form in English either! Funny, isn't it?

**Edit:** just checked this in the RAE. We *do* have the singular *tijeras* in Spanish.

Comment: Technically vacación exists in plural, but it's very rarely used and refers to the acción de vacar.

Comment: @guifa, ¿vacar o vacacionar?

Comment: Vacar. Del DRAE: «3. f. p. us. Acción de vacar (‖ quedar un empleo o cargo sin persona que lo desempeñe).» Las primeras dos acepciones están marcadas como principalmente usadas en plural, pero esa no.

Comment: Ups, quise decir en el primer mensaje que técnicamente existe en singular jaja claro que se usa casi siempre en plural

Comment: La forma singular (*vacación*) también es correcto, según [este página](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/vacaci%C3%B3n), aunque creo es mucho menos común--por lo menos en México.

Comment: Vacación does exist in the dictionary: http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=O3ZnwD07ZDXX2alAJaSy